# Multithreading with Tasks and exception handling

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application created in C# .Net 4.5. I am using multithreading via the task class. I want to add some error handling. Specifically I want any exception to bubble up to the top of my application.

Where I am stuck is how unhandled exceptions or any for that matter work whilst using tasks.

I have been reading this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx. My understanding is that if I have multiple tasks running and error happens that I have to wait until the Task.WaitAll(someTask) is called and can handle it there - is that correct? Is it possible when an error happens on one task to cancel all the other tasks before having to wait for Task.WaitAll(someTask)?

Below is a snippet of my code. I guess with nested tasks the same principle applies that I would have to wait until after both Task.WAitAll()'s have been called before handling my error? My approach for this application is rather simple, any execption thrown I want to be logged and then close the application. Just not sure how this works with tasks.

Also is it correct the way I am creating two TaskFactory's? Both methods are in different classes.

```
public void RunTimePeriods()
        {
            _taskFactory = new TaskFactory();

            Task[] taskTimePeriod = new Task[_timePeriods.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < taskTimePeriod.Length; i++)
                taskTimePeriod[i] = _taskFactory.StartNew(_timePeriods[i].RunIndicators);

            Task.WaitAll(taskTimePeriod);
         }


public void RunIndicators()
        {
            _taskFactory = new TaskFactory();

            Task[] taskIndicator = new Task[_indicator.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < taskIndicator.Length; i++)
                taskIndicator[i] = _taskFactory.StartNew(_indicator[i].Run);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you creating two factories? Can you give more details about the two `running` methods used. What is `_indicator`

Comment: Not sure. Only just thought that could be a mistake as I posted this question hence the last line. Should you only ever use one then regardless?

Comment: Look to this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx; You can throw ThrowIfCancellationRequested in the child thread and cateched on main thread (Wait) and then cancel the main task and all childrean tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible when an error happens on one task to cancel all the other tasks before having to wait for Task.WaitAll(someTask)?

The only way you can do this is to notify the other tasks to stop what they are doing. The general solution for this type of communication is to use [task cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).

Here's a good [walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx).

Comment: your right that is a good walkthrough. It also answers what I suspected about how I'm using the TaskFactory. Would I be right in saying that I do not have to create a new TaskFactory class I can instead use Task.Factory? Would you only create a new TaskFactory if there was some custom settings required for you TaskFactory?

Comment: @mHelpMe if you want to generate a custom `Task` derivative, you would need a custom factory to spawn it. You can also create a new factory instance if you want to use a different scheduler.

Comment: @mHelpMe yeah you would only need to create your own `TaskFactory` if you needed some custom configuration. If not, you should use the default instance i.e. `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`.